# Split edittext line using textwatcher in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have a layout, which i have cretaed dynamically. it has a multi-line Edittext, i have applied a text watcher on edittext so that when user is entering any text edit text line gets split after every ten characters.

To do this, i have created a text watcher like this-

```
TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() { // TextWatcher for autosave
    // feature

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
    int count) {


    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
    int after) {

    }


   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

       StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder(s.toString());

       for(int i = 10; i < s1.length(); i += 11){
           s1.insert(i, "\n");
           input.setText(s1.toString());
       }


    // alert the user
    }
};
```

But the app crashes, and shows StackOverFlow Exeption. Any idea why is so happening?
In above code, "input" is the name of my edittext.

Comment: read carefuly afterTextChanged documentation

Comment: can you please add full code,with crash report, so i can help you.

Comment: input = new EditText(Lighter_with_text_particle.this);final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(10,70);
input.setLayoutParams(lparams);input.setSingleLine(false);input.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION);input.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(25) });
input.addTextChangedListener(watcher);alert.setView(input);System.out.println("shared prefrence is"+myPrefs.getString("pankaj", str));String abc = myPrefs.getString("pankaj",str);input.addTextChangedListener(watcher);input.setText(abc);

Answer (score 1):

If input is your EditText then thats what is happening:

You type a letter, TextWatcher.afterTextChanged is called, you change text there so TextWatcher.afterTextChanged is called again, and this happens till end of the stack

```
TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() { // TextWatcher for autosave
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        input.removeTextChangedListener(this);

        StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder(s.toString());

        for(int i = 10; i < s1.length(); i += 11){
            s1.insert(i, "\n");
            input.setText(s1.toString());
        }

        input.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }
};
```

Comment: come on why so complex? add/remove the listener is not so fast, why not using a boolean flag?

Comment: you are generally right, but it is more elegant in OO world :) I would change that only if performance become an issue

Comment: @Gaskoin your answer is right,using removeTextChangedListener doesn't crash the app. but it's breaking the line on each character after i have entered 11th character

Comment: Thats true, but that is your code, not mine. I've only presented what is an issue, and how to avoid it, but how it should work is up to you.